# Assets pipeline doesn't import other gems in 'application.scss'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to setup the gem `bootstrap-sass` on my Rails app [as explained here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). I've renamed my `application.css` file as `application.scss`. Here is the content of the file:

```
  /*
   * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
   * listed below.
   *
   * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
   * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
   *
   * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
   * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
   * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
   * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
   */
   @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
   @import "bootstrap";
```

But when compiling this file in CSS, the Asset Pipelien doesn't import anything and outputs a CSS file with the same content as the SASS one.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: yes, I've deleted precompiled or temporary stuff too